# Что верно: Е или Ю?

Tags: орфография

"Как правило, организация уголка охраны труда, в том числе функции контроля, возлагаЕ(Ю)тся на службу охраны труда."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь - "возлагаЕтся". Ведь речь идет об организации уголка охраны труда, которая, собственно, и возлагается.

Answer (score 0):

Но возлагается не только организация, но ещё  и функции... (Причём *функции*  стоит во множественном числе.) Получается, подлежащие *организация* и *функции*, тогда казуемое должно стоять во множественном числе. Наверно ,так. Опровергните кто-нибудь меня.

Comment: Опровергните себя сами.

Answer (score 0):

Организация  - подлежащее, возлагается - сказуемое, согласуются в числе. А вот про функции контроля - непонятно по сути.Уголок будет  исполнять функции контроля? Может, лучше так: "Как правило, организация контроля (за чем? надо уточнить )и уголка охраны труда возлагается на службу охраны труда."

Comment: Все понятно, если вдуматься. Функции контроля - составная часть организации. Может и не очень естественно с организационной точки зрения, но синтаксис и грамматика не нарушается.